# "Additional data from the script executed" message in Inkscape

Tags: python, inkscape

This is very irritating. I'm Using Ubuntu Oneiric and when I use Inkscape and make a couple of copy-paste operations inside the image, I get the following popup message:

```
Inkscape has received additional data from the script executed.
The script did not return an error, but this may indicate the results
will not be as expected.

The fantastic lxml wrapper for libxml2 is required by inkex.py and therefore
this extension. Please download and install the latest version from
http://cheeseshop.python.org/pypi/lxml/, or install it through your
package manager by a command like: sudo apt-get install python-lxml
```

I tried updating the python-lxml package ans it's no use. Any other solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/965623

as mentioned in post #5 in the thread:

I had a clipboard manager installed on my debian 6; disabling it solved the annoyance factor -- it appears this is a known bug.

Comment: I've done a clean install Precise Pangolin (12.04). I hope not to see this issue again.